# Separate multiple rows of data into data frames of one row each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, azure-logic-apps

There is a data frame that holds the data retrieved from the SQL DB.
Assume that you have five rows of data as follows (I don't know how many rows there are in the actual data).

```
dfDB
   C1   C2   C3
1  A   112  7449
2  B   113  5711
3  C   113  8290
4  D   114  2784
5  E   113  4886
```

I want to create a data frame with these data separated by one rows.

```
dfDB_1
   C1   C2   C3
1  A   112  7449

dfDB_2
   C1   C2   C3
2  B   113  5711

dfDB_3
   C1   C2   C3
3  C   113  8290

dfDB_4
   C1   C2   C3
4  D   114  2784

dfDB_5
   C1   C2   C3
5  E   113  4886
```

Also, if possible, I would like to output the data of each data frame as an Excel file, is that possible?
I am thinking of using SPO or Blob Storage to create Excel files.

```
dfDB_1 -> dfDB_1.xlsx
dfDB_2 -> dfDB_2.xlsx
dfDB_3 -> dfDB_3.xlsx
dfDB_4 -> dfDB_4.xlsx
dfDB_5 -> dfDB_5.xlsx
```

If anyone has any good ideas, could you please let me know?

Best regards,
Lopez

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list `df_row = []` and

```
df.apply(lambda x: df_row.append(df.loc[[x.name]]), axis=1)
```

Then for instance

```
df_row[0]
# Out: 
#   C1   C2    C3
# 0  A  112  7449

df_row[1]
# Out: 
#   C1   C2    C3
# 1  B  113  5711

type(df_row[0])
# Out: 
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `iterrows()` and list comprehension

```
list_of_dfs = row.to_frame().T for _,row in dfDB.iterrows()]
```

output (a list of dataframes)

```
[  C1   C2    C3
 1  A  112  7449,
   C1   C2    C3
 2  B  113  5711,
   C1   C2    C3
 3  C  113  8290,
   C1   C2    C3
 4  D  114  2784,
   C1   C2    C3
 5  E  113  4886]
```

eg

```
list_of_dfs[0]
```

output

```
    C1  C2  C3
1   A   112 7449
```

to save to excel use `to_excel` in a loop, eg:

```
for n,df in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    df.to_excel(f'dfDB_{n}.xlsx')
```